# My collapsable item doesn't transition smoothly on close, bottom border jumps to the top

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, styled-components

I created a collapsable item with React and everything works fine except for when the collapsible div closes. Instead of closing smoothly and bringing the border bottom to the top with the same smoothness it opens, it just goes right up to the top and it looks glitchy. I'm using styled components as follows:

```
const CollapsableContent = styled.div`
text-align: center;
font-size: 1.2rem;
opacity: ${props => (props.open ? "1" : "0")};
max-height: ${props => (props.open ? "100%" : "0")};
padding: ${props => (props.open ? "15px" : "0 15px")};
overflow: hidden;
transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
```

`

Here's the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-moon-v01vq?file=/src/App.js) link for more detailed code. Click anywhere on the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For animation to work you need two valid values (range of values), since 100% isn't valid value unless your div is inside a container that has a known height, basicaly you are telling your browser that the div will take 100%, but 100% of what ?, the solution is to put the div inside another one (that have a valid heigth) or use somthing like

```
max-height: ${props => (props.open ? "1000px" : "0px")};
```

since it is max-height and not height it will not take extra space.